# fiscal calculations using tsql

Tags: t-sql

I want to find fiscal month and year based on a date.
How  Can I do it using TSQL?

I have SQl server 2008.

Any help?

Regards
Manjot

Comment: When does your fiscal year start?

Comment: I don't think that is built in, so you are going to have to calculate it. Since I don't know what a "fiscal month" or "fiscal year" is, you'll have to define it.

Comment: My fiscal month starts on 1 April.
Not sure about the year.
I want to find fiscal month and quater.
Do you see people recording fiscal year as well? I just thought of recording it but it is not neccessday (if I cant calculate it :-) ). What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You store a table of days (one row per day) with date and columns for the fiscal year and month that are pertinent to your org (fiscal month and year vary from org to org).

SQL as a rule is much better at looking up data rather than computing it. A fiscal calendar table for the next century would take a puny amount of data and save tones of cycles in computation.

Comment: Thanks for this.
But if I have a date how can I find fiscal quater or month?
Just add 1 for quater and add 3 for month?
What about year?

Comment: You have columns for quarter and month and any other fiscal period you're interested in, down to week (retail usually has special weeks). You never add or substract anything, just lookup a date and see what fiscal year, month, quarter it belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a table defining your fiscal year, and build queries based on that. Trying to do something tricky in TSQL is only going to give you nightmares.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a number of SSRS reports, being an university we have an August fiscal year so I created a query that would take the start date for the week and determine which year it was in. In this example I've used Getdate() instead.

```
SELECT
(CASE
    WHEN DatePart(MM,(cast(floor(cast(DATEADD(dd,((DATEPART(dw,GetDate()))-1)*-1,GetDate()) as float)) as datetime))) < 8 
                THEN DATEPART(Year,GetDate())
    ELSE DATEPART(Year,GetDate())+1
END) AS FinYear,

(CASE 
    WHEN DATEPART(wk,GetDate()) - DATEPART(wk,CAST(CAST(DATEPART(yy,GetDate()) AS Char)+'-08-01' AS Datetime)) > 0
                THEN  DATEPART(wk,GetDate()) - DATEPART(wk,CAST(CAST(DATEPART(yy,GetDate()) AS Char)+'-08-01' AS Datetime))
    ELSE DATEPART(wk,GetDate()) - DATEPART(wk,CAST(CAST(DATEPART(yy,GetDate()) AS Char)+'-08-01' AS Datetime)) + 52
END) As FinWeek
```

It does the job but still has the disadvantage of only being able to work on the start date of the week so if there are weeks which mainly lie in the next fiscal year it won't adjust for that. Mind you having said that it took M$ 15 years to get ISO standard calendar weeks...